# Why MessageBox.Show is not working in that code?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to run ImageView_Fullscreen function from shimgvw.dll 32-bit from Windows XP on my 64-bit Windows 8 machine with my C# application (Target Framework: 4, AppType: Console Apllication). Function is not working at all, but I see a strange picture that MessageBox.Show doesn't work after calling it. Why is this? Explain me it, please.
Here is my app C# code:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "AddAtomW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern ushort AddAtom(string lpString);

//shimgvw.dll is from WindowsXP (6.00.2900.5512 version)
//For ImageView_FullscreenW and CharSet.Unicode result is the same
[DllImport(@"D:\Graphic Soft\ShimgvwXP\shimgvw.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "ImageView_FullscreenA", SetLastError = true)]
static extern void ImageView_Fullscreen(IntPtr i, IntPtr dll, string path, int wndMode);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Test"); //Working!
    AddAtom("FailObsoleteShellAPIs");   //Without that atom LoadLibrary fails

    IntPtr hinstance = LoadLibrary(@"D:\Graphic Soft\ShimgvwXP\shimgvw.dll");
    if (hinstance != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test"); //Working!

        //Not doing anything...Though it must show image. Image is exists
        ImageView_Fullscreen(IntPtr.Zero, hinstance, @"D:\Wallpapers\0001_2.jpg", 3);

        uint err = GetLastError();
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + err); //NOT WORKING!!!
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + err);  //Working. Prints out: "Error: 0"

        //Not doing anything...This image is NOT exists
        ImageView_Fullscreen(IntPtr.Zero, hinstance, @"D:\Wallpapers\not_existed_image.jpg", 3);

        err = GetLastError();
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + err); //NOT WORKING!!!
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + err);  //Working. Prints out: "Error: 2 (code ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)"
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: With regard to your code comment `//Not doing anything...Though it will show image...` How can it both not doing anything and doing something at once??? And with regard to your explanation: "_but I see a strange picture_" How strange exactly is that picture? What does it depict, what does it look like?

Comment: Try catch...do some logging...find out your error

Comment: You do realize that this is completely unsupported (and a violation of the Windows XP license).

Answer (score -2):

Instead of Using Message Box,
You can use:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Trim(), "javascript:alert('This is my First Answer on Stack Overflow');", true);
            return;**

string abc = "StackOverFlow"; 

ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock((Page)(HttpContext.Current.Handler), typeof(Page), "alert", "javascript:alert('" + Convert.ToString(abc("Cannot Be Empty. ")) + "');", true); return;
```

### [image]

Comment: The OP is using a ConsoleApp, not  a WebApp. ScriptManager is specific to ASP.Net webforms